# twitter api updating status' and databases'

Tags: mysql, database, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to learn how to work with twitter api. I'm still a little confused. If I want users to tweet using my input text boxes on my site, do I still need a database for those tweets? Or does the api handle the storage for the tweets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about your requirement and then your design pattern. Infact You don't need any database to store tweets. In your case where you just want to tweet, You can do it without DB. Infact twitter-rest-api https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api is very good.

If you need to made frequent api call from your app, you can use caching to avoid too many frequent calls. For reference https://github.com/atsiddiqui/ReTweeted

Comment: Thanks everyone, all gave good answers. but your stats are lower than everyone else so i'll bump up your stats :) cheers all!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a database to store the tweets.  Twitter stores them.

Answer (score 1):

Once you use the Twitter API to send the tweet data to Twitter.com, it is stored on Twitter.com's storage system. So, it is in a way *handled* by the api. It does not matter to Twitter whether you stored them in your own database or not.

But it is good practice to store the information in you own server database for record purpose. For example, you might want to know the statistics -- how many users use your service, what is the average use of it. 
It may help investigating issues (sometimes legal) like when an user complains that your site published offensive tweet to his account. Then, you can track and check your database.
There are many more cases when you want to see the records in your system.